# Angular reactive form controls mark untouched after data submitted

Tags: angular

I have a form on a mat-sidenav. The first when I use the form to submit data it works fine with all validation. Then the second when i open the form the form doesn't get reset to its pristine state. This my form setup

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.saleForm = new FormGroup({//Sale Form Initialization
      'accountNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[0-9-]*'),
      Validators.minLength(13),
      Validators.maxLength(13)]),
      'customerName': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z. ]+')]),
})
```

And here is how I clear the form from all validations after the form submit button is pressed.

```
this.saleForm.markAsPristine();
this.saleForm.markAsUntouched();
this.saleForm.reset();
```

Saw you a few posts on stackoverflow thats how these code above. Here is the picture when the form is opened the second time. It is expected to open the form with the focus on Account Number field.
[image]

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav postion="start" mode="over" style="width:20%;">
    <mat-icon (click)="sidenavClose(sidenav)" style="float:right;opacity:0.5;margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;cursor:pointer">close</mat-icon>
    <form *ngIf="sidenavStartUpMode === 'sale'" [formGroup]="saleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaleOrUpgrade()" novalidate style="background-color:#e6f2ff;height:auto;padding:7px;">
        <!--novalidate specifies no validation to be done on the DOM-->
        <mat-label>TRACK SALE</mat-label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput #accountNumber placeholder="Account Number" formControlName="accountNumber">
                <mat-hint align="end">{{ accountNumber.value.length }} / 13</mat-hint>
                <mat-error *ngIf="saleForm.get('accountNumber').touched && saleForm.get('accountNumber').invalid">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="saleForm.get('accountNumber').hasError('minlength')">
                        <strong>Account number has to be 13 digits!</strong>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Customer Name" formControlName="customerName">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="matRadioButton">
            <p style="padding:1px; color:#2775b4">
                <b>Select Package</b>
            </p>
            <mat-radio-group formControlName="packageName">
                <mat-radio-button class="pkgCampaignRadios" *ngFor="let pkg of bs.packages" [value]="pkg.cbsCode">
                    {{pkg.cbsCode}}
                </mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
            <button mat-button type="button" (click)="openAddonsDialog()" style="margin-top:10px;padding:3px;width:100%;background-color:#367db9;color:white;border-radius: 2px;">
                <b>{{selectedAddons | addonsSpaceAddPipe}}</b>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="matRadioButton">
            <p style="padding:1px; color:#2775b4">
                <b>Select Campaign</b>
            </p>
            <mat-radio-group formControlName="campaignName">
                <mat-radio-button class="pkgCampaignRadios" *ngFor="let campaign of bs.campaigns" [value]="campaign.campaignName">
                    {{campaign.campaignName}}
                </mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="crew" (change)="crewSelected($event.source.value)" style="margin-left:50px;text-align:center">
                <mat-button-toggle value="FFM" (click)="datePicker.open()">FFM
                    <h6 style="color:red;font-style:bold;font-size:13px" *ngIf="crew === 'FFM'">{{ datePickerInput }}</h6>
                </mat-button-toggle>
                <mat-button-toggle value="9000">9000
                </mat-button-toggle>
                <mat-button-toggle value="8555">8555
                </mat-button-toggle>
            </mat-button-toggle-group>
            <mat-form-field style="padding:0px;width:1px;visibility:hidden;">
                <input formControlName="postDate" #date matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="" (dateInput)="addEvent(date)"
                    (dateChange)="addEvent(date)">
                <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Notes" matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="2" matAutosizeMaxRows="5" formControlName="notes"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" style="width:100%;height:50px;" (click)="sidenavClose(sidenav)" mat-raised-button
            [disabled]="saleForm.invalid">Track Sale</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your form template ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun I have shared the template.

Comment: The code looks like it should work, can you make a runnable reproduction stackblitz for your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

`this.saleForm.reset()` itself should work.

Maybe your issue is that you have another error in your logs? As I see you set some additional formControlName like **packageName**, **campaignName**, **crew**, **postDate**, **notes** which are not created in your formGroup. This might cause a problem.

Also: `this.saleForm.reset()` by itself is enough. As the documentation says

> Resets the FormGroup, marks all descendants are marked pristine and untouched, and
>   the value of all descendants to null.

So you don't need to call `markAsPristine()` and `markAsUntouched()` additionally.